# Local extremes and $y^3-y+1=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Find local extremes:
$$F(x,y)=y^4-8xy-4y+8x^2$$

$$F_x = -8y + 16x=0$$
$$F_y = 4y^3 - 8x-4=0$$

$$y^3-y+1=0$$

And I stopped in this moment... How to solve it?

Comment: It doesn't give any nice result there is probably something wrong with the question

Comment: $y^3-y-1=0$ instead of $y^3-y+1=0$, I think.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy silly! :) It's the reduced cubic equation!

You have to propose a solution of the form $y = u + v$

Then you get:

$$u^3 + v^3 + 3uv^2 + 3u^2v - u - v - 1 = 0$$

and then you propose:

$$u^3 + v^3 - 1 = 0$$

$$3uv - 1 = 0$$

Which gives:

$$u^3 + \dfrac{1}{27u^3} - 1 = 0$$

and

$$v = \dfrac{1}{3u}$$

So:

$$u^6 - u^3 + \dfrac{1}{27} = 0$$

Now if we propose:

$$u^3 = t$$

We have:

$$t^2 - t + \dfrac{1}{27} = 0$$

Which is solvable through quadratic equation.

That would give you two solution for $u^3 = t$ but you would need to find the 3 solution for each solution. Each of this are the cubic root of $t$ times $\exp(\frac{2i\pi n}{3})$, with $n = 0, 1 , 2$.

Also bear in mind that $u$ an $v$ are linked though:

$$v = \dfrac{1}{3u}$$

that would give you 3 points, probable only one is real, I'm think it would be the one with $n = 0$.

I believe the solutions are

$$y_0 = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{69}}{18}} + \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{\sqrt{69}}{18}}$$

$$y_1 = -\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{16}+\dfrac{\sqrt{69}}{144}} - \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{16}-\dfrac{\sqrt{69}}{144}} - \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{16}+\dfrac{\sqrt{23}}{16}}i + \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{16}+\dfrac{\sqrt{23}}{16}}i$$

$$y_2 = -\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{16}+\dfrac{\sqrt{69}}{144}} - \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{16}-\dfrac{\sqrt{69}}{144}} + \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{16}+\dfrac{\sqrt{23}}{16}}i - \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{16}+\dfrac{\sqrt{23}}{16}}i$$

So the solution you need is:

$$y_0 = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{69}}{18}} + \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{\sqrt{69}}{18}}$$

$$x_0 = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{16}+\dfrac{\sqrt{69}}{144}} + \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{16}-\dfrac{\sqrt{69}}{144}}$$